# Dbeaver Exception: Data Source was invalid

Tags: hive, dbeaver, spark-hive

I am trying to work with Dbeaver and processing data via Spark Hive. The connection is stable as the following command works:

```
select * from database.table limit 100
```

However, as soon as I differ from the simple fetching query I get an exception. E.g. runing the query

```
select count(*) from database.table limit 100
```

results in the exception:

> SQL Error [2] [08S01]: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error
>   while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2
>   from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed,
>   vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1526294345914_23590_12_00,
>   diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1526294345914_23590_12_00 [Map 1]
>   killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: postings
>   initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1526294345914_23590_12_00 [Map 1],
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception:
>   Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad
>   Request; Request ID: 95BFFF20D13AECDA), S3 Extended Request ID:
>   fSbzZDf/Xi0b+CL99c5DKi8GYrJ7TQXj5/WWGCiCpGa6JU5SGeoxA4lunoxPCNBJ2MPA3Hxh14M=

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

400/Bad Request is the S3/AWS Generic "didn't like your payload/request/auth" response. There's some details in the [ASF S3A docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html), but that is for the ASF connector, not the amazon one (which yours is, from the stack trace). Bad endpoint for v4-authenticated buckets is usually problem #1, after that...who knows?

1. try and do some basic `hadoop fs -ls s3://bucket/path` operations first.
2. you can try running the [cloudstore diagnostics](https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore) against it; that's my first call for debugging a client. Its not explicitly EMR-s3-connector aware though, so it won't look at the credentials in any detail